# trigger adf pipeline based on file creation in sftp folder

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an azure data factory pipeline that copies a file from sftp folder and drops to azure blob storage.  From there I want to link it to a databricks notebook and do some processing.

Right now I triggered manually but I would like the ADF pipeline to trigger when the file is created in the sftp folder.  searching online I see 4 years ago someone used a azure logic app to accomplish this.

Is there a newer way?  That was 4 years ago.  Is there some new built in functionality to have ADF trigger directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately ADF doesnt have event trigger based on traditional SFTP aspect.
You can use Logic app/Power automate and in turn trigger the ADF pipeline.

You can use the SFTP support in Azure blob storage feature :
MSFT doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support

And then the blob trigger of ADF would work

Answer (score 1):

> You can consider writing code in azure function, which till watch for
> file in SFTP and once file available it will trigger your ADF
> pipeline.

Please note, in your Azure Function code, you can write logic to make API call to ADF to run the pipeline.